# inside left join select with case when select where grouped by

Tags: sql, database

I have this code which returns the result I want;

```
select stktype, Part_No,
Case when stktype = 'labour' then Part_No END
from fleet_job_jobdetails
where JobCode = '176071' AND StkType = 'labour'
group by part_no, StkType
```

stktype Part_No (No column name)
Labour  ANDR    ANDR

when I add it to my larger code i get error

```
LEFT JOIN (
           SELECT   jobcode
           ,        SUM(linecost) AS totalcost
           ,        SUM(CASE WHEN stktype = 'sublet' THEN linecost
                             ELSE 0
                        END) AS subletcost
           ,        SUM(CASE WHEN stktype = 'labour' THEN linecost
                             ELSE 0
                        END) AS labourcost
           ,        SUM(CASE WHEN stktype = 'part' THEN linecost
                             ELSE 0
                        END) AS partscost
           ,        SUM(CASE WHEN stktype NOT IN ('sublet', 'labour', 'part') THEN linecost
                             ELSE 0
                        END) AS othercost
        ,           **CASE WHEN (select StkType from fleet_job_jobdetails WHERE stktype = 'labour')  = 'labour' THEN Part_No  ELSE '' END AS Mech**
           FROM     fleet_job_jobdetails
           GROUP BY jobcode, Part_No
          ) a
        ON fleet_job_jobmaster.jobcode = a.jobcode
```

Comment: (select COUNT(*) stktype, part_no, Case when stktype = 'labour' then Part_No END from fleet_job_jobdetails where stktype = 'labour' group by part_no, StkType)

Comment: I get an error Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Part_No* **only in this case**

```
** CASE
                       WHEN (select StkType
                               from fleet_job_jobdetails
                              WHERE stktype = 'labour') = 'labour' THEN
                        Part_No
```

so there will be no Part_No situation,you must revise the statement to make sure the *Part_No* exist and not in `WHEN THEN`

**OR** you just only group by `jobcode`

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS:**

```
LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT   jobcode
       ,        SUM(linecost) AS totalcost
       ,        SUM(CASE WHEN stktype = 'sublet' THEN linecost
                         ELSE 0
                    END) AS subletcost
       ,        SUM(CASE WHEN stktype = 'labour' THEN linecost
                         ELSE 0
                    END) AS labourcost
       ,        SUM(CASE WHEN stktype = 'part' THEN linecost
                         ELSE 0
                    END) AS partscost
       ,        SUM(CASE WHEN stktype NOT IN ('sublet', 'labour', 'part') THEN linecost
                         ELSE 0
                    END) AS othercost
                    --Here seems subquery is not required we can simply replace with it
        ,           CASE WHEN stktype = 'labour' THEN Part_No  ELSE '' END AS Mech 
       FROM     fleet_job_jobdetails
       GROUP BY jobcode, Part_No
      ) a
    ON fleet_job_jobmaster.jobcode = a.jobcode
```